# Is Cosmos DB v2 SDK PreferredLocations Property available in V3 SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Recently, I'm working on a project migrating to Cosmos DB V3 SDK. V2 SDK provides [PreferredLocations property from ConnectionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet). My project uses provided locations to construct a list of backup regions to connect instead when throttling occurs.

Searching the cosmos DB GitHub repo, [the ConnectionPolicy changed to be used only for internal purposes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/ConnectionPolicy.cs). I've tried to find a similar feature in V3 SDK but failed. Is there an interface in V3 providing a similar feature as the PreferredLocations property of ConnectionPolicy in V2 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the property you are looking for is [`ApplicationPreferredRegions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.applicationpreferredregions?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-cosmosclientoptions-applicationpreferredregions) in [`CosmosClientOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet).

From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.applicationpreferredregions?view=azure-dotnet#remarks):

> When this property is specified, the SDK will use the region list in
> the provided order to define the endpoint failover order. This
> configuration is an alternative to ApplicationRegion, either one can
> be set but not both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My case, I just use primary reason for connection. For example, with primaryReason is West-US, when I call [ConnectionPolicy.SetCurrentLocation(primaryReason)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/c578e89da99620366210d114b49b512e3c4a6d00/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/ConnectionPolicy.cs#L65) using V2 SDK, it automatically populates preferred region list and saved as PreferredLocations property which is public. In V3 SDK, all features look like moved as internal only.

Comment: Can you try the same with [`ApplicationRegion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.applicationregion?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-cosmosclientoptions-applicationregion) property?